# Free version of Ansible won't allow me to move a file from Ansible server to client servers

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ansible

I can ssh between the server with ansible and the client server.  Both servers are AWS instances of Ubuntu.  This command shows a success with the client server:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

This is the contents of my playbook site.yml:

```
  vars:
    http_port: 80
    max_clients: 200
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: Move the file foo
    action: file src=/tmp/crowded/foo dest=/tmp/crowded/foo
```

4) I try to run this playbook when I am not root:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts -k -K site.yml -vvvv
```

But I get this (where x.x.x.x is the IP address of the client server):

```
fatal: [x.x.x.x] => SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-x.x.x.x-22-root" does not exist


...

debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).


TASK: [Move the file foo] *****************************************************
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/ubuntu/site.retry

x.x.x.x              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

What should I do to move an Ansible file?  I want to understand how playbooks work.

Answer (score 1):

The file module is not meant to copy files in Ansible, but rather to simply ensure a file exists, change permissions, create directories & symlinks, etc.  If you want to copy a file from the ansible server to a client machine then you want to use either the copy or the template module.

I suggest you take a very close look at the documentation for the [file](http://docs.ansible.com/file_module.html), [copy](http://docs.ansible.com/copy_module.html), and [template](http://docs.ansible.com/template_module.html) modules.  Note in particular that the file module, which you used in your example, only recognizes the `src` parameter when you are creating a symlink:

> path of the file to link to (applies only to state=link). Will accept absolute, relative and nonexisting paths. Relative paths are not expanded.

All this has nothing to do, however, with the error that you're encountering:

> debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
>   Permission denied (publickey).

You seem to have an issue with the SSH authentication used by Ansible. You might need to either load your SSH private key into ssh-agent as described in the Ansible [Getting Started](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_getting_started.html) section and/or make sure you are setting the [private_key_file](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#private-key-file) and [remote_user](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#remote-user) values in your ansible.cfg file properly.